# How to verify a user information object created in one method in a different method

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# and haven't had much luck with figuring this out.

I need some help with verifying a user inputted email and password in a different method from the one it was constructed in.

Below is the code I have so far to do this. It uses a simple text based userinterface from another file to gather the userinputted data which is not included here but is fairly simple.

What I basically want to do is be able to verify the information created in the ClientData method in the ClientEnter method.

I'm probably going about this all wrong but I thought that creating an empty c1 object outside of both methods and updating it inside the ClientData method would allow me to do this but it does not and only allows me to log in with empty input.

Any help with how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main( string[] args ) {
        MainMenu();
    }

    static void MainMenu() {
        const int REGISTER = 0, LOGIN = 1, EXIT = 2;

        bool running = true;

        while ( running ) {
            int option = UserInterface.GetOption("Please select one of the following:",
                "Register as new Client", "Login as exisitng Client", "Exit"
            );

            switch ( option ) {
                case REGISTER: 
                    RegisterClient(); 
                    break;
                case LOGIN: 
                    LoginClient();
                    break;
                case EXIT: 
                    running = false; 
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }


    ClientInfo c1 = new ClientInfo(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);

    private static void RegisterClient()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.ClientData();

    }

    public void ClientData()
    {
        string Ufullname = UserInterface.GetInput("Full name");
        string Uemail = UserInterface.GetInput("Email");
        string Upassword = UserInterface.GetPassword("Password");
        string Uaddress = UserInterface.GetInput("Address");

        var c1 = new ClientInfo(Ufullname, Uemail, Upassword, Uaddress);

        Console.WriteLine($"{c1.fullname} registered successfully");
    }

    private static void LoginClient()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.ClientEnter();

    }

    public void ClientEnter()
    {
        string userEmail = UserInterface.GetInput("Email");
        string userPassword = UserInterface.GetPassword("Password");
        if (c1.password == userPassword && c1.email == userEmail)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {c1.fullname} {c1.email}");
            ClientMenu();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email or password is incorrect");
        }
    }
    
}

class ClientInfo
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    public ClientInfo(string Tfullname, string Temail, string Tpassword, string Taddress)
    {
        fullname = Tfullname;
        email = Temail;
        password = Tpassword;
        address = Taddress;
    }
```

Comment: `public void ClientEnter()` should be changed to `public static void ClientEnter()`. you need to remove `Program p = new Program();` and call methods directly as `ClientEnter()` and `ClientData();` Also `public void ClientData()` should be changed to `public static void ClientData()`

Comment: `ClientInfo c1 = new ClientInfo` should be changed to `static ClientInfo c1 = new ClientInfo`.  `var c1 = new ClientInfo` should be changed to `c1 = new ClientInfo`